# aws CLI: get-job-output erroring with either Errno9 Bad File Descriptor or Errno9 no such file or directory

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I'm having some problems with retrieving job output from an AWS glacier vault.

I initiated a job (aws glacier initiate-job), the job is indicated as complete via aws glacier, and then I tried to retrieve the job output

```
aws glacier get-job-output --account-id - --vault-name <myvaultname> --job-id <jobid> output.json
```

However, I receive an error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output.json'

Thinking that perhaps the file needed be created first, and if i did create the file first, (which really doesn't make sense), one would receive the [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor error.

I'm currently using the following version of the AWS CLI:
aws-cli/2.4.10 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

I tried using the aws CLI from both an Administrative and non-Administrative command prompt with the same result.  Any ideas on making this work?

Answer (score 1):

From a related [reported issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2855) you can try run this command in a DOS window::

```
copy "c:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\botocore\vendored\requests\cacert.pem" "c:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\certifi"
```

It seems to be an certificate error

Comment: I saw this in another search, but didn't think it applied.  However when looking at this again, I realized the issue (my dumb mistake).  I have folder protection turned on my system, and the target output.json file was in a protected folder.  So, thanks.. after looking into that again and trying some things.. this got me on the right track, when I noticed some pop-ups about folder protection.